# pagination with flutter bloc package loss scroll position

Tags: flutter, pagination, flutter-bloc, flutter-state, scroll-position

while am using flutter_bloc 6.0 I got a problem that I wrapped scaffold with bloc builder and when new state its value will be appended to the defined list of empty. well on new sate value appended but the UI rebuild all and lost the scroll position and it went to the initial offset position. how can I solve this properly.

Comment: can you please share some code ?